# How does the form affect sound traveling thru solid material

Tags: waves, acoustics

Take for example a boom pole: does its diameter affect how sound (like handling noise) is traveling towards the mic? Would a short section of smaller diameter (say 10% of the regular diameter) reduce the transmitted energy? And if so, would it affect all frequencies or would it act maybe as a hp or lp filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elastic systems (like your boom pole) have a resonant frequency which is related to the form of the system. Because a boom pole involves fairly complex junctions between solids it's considerably more complex than a hollow cylinder.  Still, you might start in your estimation using the equation for the [natural frequency of a simply-supported hollow cylinder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFfYw.jpg):

$$ f = 2 \pi  L^2 \ A \; \sqrt{E \;  \frac{I}{m}} $$

where:

- $A$ = 9.87 for first mode
- $L$ = length of pole (m)
- $E$ = Young's modulus (N/m^2)
- $I$ = area moment of inertia (m^4)
- $m$ = mass per unit length of the pole (kg/m)

Your question about adding a short section of smaller diameter seems to me to be a question of *insertion loss*. Essentially what you're doing is breaking the pipe into three coupled systems - the first (now, shorter) tube of the original diameter, a tube of smaller diameter in the middle, and a second (also shorter) tube of the original diameter at the end.  I suspect it would act to make the transfer of energy less efficient and would reduce the levels at the end of the boom.

I don't know how to perform the calculations, but you'd expect - for the same material and wall thickness - the smaller diameter tube to be less elastic.  Thus, a higher Young's modulus, thus a higher natural frequency.

The last part of your question involves *impedance*.

> Would it affect all frequencies or would it act maybe as a hp or lp filter?

You'd expect your smaller section to be driven by the natural frequency of the larger diameter section near your hands.  That is, a driving frequency < the natural frequency.  As above, we expect quite a bit of dampening of the lower pipe's resonant frequency.

[image]

But we should expect the impulsive sound of handling noise to be broadband in nature. 
 In that case the center section would do a good job of transmitting energy at it's natural frequency, which would be dampened again somewhat by the larger section of pipe at the end.  Again, I'm not sure of the calculations but intuitively that strikes me as more of a bandpass filter than either a high or lowpass filter.